# I would like to use my Miele steam oven to cook a steak and kidney pudding. How long should I cook it for?

Tags: steaming, steamed-pudding

I would like to make Nigella's steak and kidney pudding on New Year's Day. I've successfully made it before lots of times by following her recipe to steam it in a steamer on the hob for 3 hours but this time I'd like to use my Miele steam oven. How long should I steam the pudding please? Also, does anyone know where I can find conversion charts?